# Show editor tabs in Presentation mode

Tags: intellij-idea

When I am in a presentation mode I want have Editor Tabs enabled. Now they are disabled, so when I enter presentation mode I cannot move tabs right or to the opposite group. Is there a possibility to enable them?

Comment: No: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165833.

Comment: Related, having tabs in presentation mode: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120266/Add-optional-tabs-when-in-presentation-mode